# chrome desktop notification- how to add more words

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, notifications

I realized only the first few words are displayed in Chrome Desktop notification.

I used chrome.notifications.create() API to create the notification. Is there a way to show more words/lines in the message?

I noticed there is a list notification type, but on Mac, only the first item is displayed.

Is there a way to display more words/add more lines to the Chrome desktop notification for Mac?

Comment: You can create a picture using canvas, output the text there, and show that picture in a notification.

Comment: Thanks @wOxxOm! Apparently Mac will not display the image :(